# Speed of the Coulomb field measured to be "infinite"

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, coulombs-law

The paper "[Measuring Propagation Speed of Coulomb Fields](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2913)" by R. de Sangro et al points out that:

> ...the Lienard-Weichert retarded potential leads to the same formula
> as the one obtained assuming that the electric field propagates with
> ***infinite*** velocity

Moreover, they conduct an experiment which purportedly measures a
"rigid" (aka infinite velocity) $-\nabla \phi $ ("Coulomb Field") and further claim:

> The Feynman interpretation of the L.W. formula for uniformly moving
> charges does not show consistency with our experimental data.

This violates special relativity because information can be transmitted at infinite speed simply by changing the position of a charge and measuring, at a large distance, the associated changes in $-\nabla \phi $.

Where did they go wrong?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I just read the paper and they definitely didn't provide evidence to support the second statement you quoted in the question.  They collected some (very imprecise because of their lack of knowledge about the electron beam's shape) data which was consistent with all of the theories in question.   It was a non-result, essentially.

Comment: Also note how their sensor results are mostly oscillations at the natural frequency of their sensors.  They got only a little bit of information about the shape of the electric field "wake" of the beam, and what little they got was made useless by their lack of knowledge of the shape of the beam itself.

Comment: THe most important bit of the paper:

Comment: "One issue common to all our measurements
stands out clearly: in the same experimental conditions (sensor position,
trigger timing, cable lengths, DAQ settings) the two distributions are
different. We attribute this difference to less than perfect reliability in
the beam delivery conditions (launch angles, total beam length, charge
distribution in the beam pulse length, stray magnetic fields, etc.), over
which we had little control."

Comment: Why even publish this failure?

Comment: The "less than perfect reliability" as evidenced by the 2 distributes in Figure 6 doesn't seem to be a great impediment given their all statistical moments are within 20% of each other.  They say:  "We find experimentally η = 7.5×10−2± 3%, however due to various systematic effects we believe our calibration to be
good to ≈ 20%, in absolute terms."  The effect they were looking for exceeds that by a large margin, does it not?

Answer (score 1):

There exists a [different interpretation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00710) of the measurements in the paper:

I copy from the concluding paragraph:

> Our conclusion is that most probably the signal registered in the Frascati experiment [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00710) originates from
>   the radiation due to the acceleration of the beam, and
>   does not belong to the Coulomb disk of the charge. As
>   for the latter, it should be sought for hundreds of meters
>   ahead, already outside of the laboratory, after the beam
>   itself is absorbed by its concrete wall, unless, certainly,
>   it is screened by other possible objects

Answer (score 0):

The experiment is correct but it only proves that field around electrons is static. The same result would be when replacing the electron beam with collimated microwave beam... Electric field in the direction perpendicular to the wave's propagation is static...

Answer (score -1):

The "Frascati experiment" should be an incentive to improve on our understanding of the electron itself. In spite of P.A.M. Dirac's work to find a solution describing the electron as an eigenstate of a quantum-mechanical equation, no efforts have been made - to my knowledge - to calculate as well the corresponding eigenfunction in space-time. Actually we think of the electron as of some little ball, having some strange property attached to it which we call the electric field. Such mental artifact is not supposed to fit experimental data. We will furthermore need to fit as well the "Zitterbewegung" into the picture of the electron in space-time. The "Frascati experiment" points strongly toward the assumption that the electron does not HAVE a field, but that it IS a stationary electromagnetic field in space-time.